Navier-stokes pressure term
I am trying to solve the incompressible navier-stokes equations in 2D. As I understand it, my solution method is pretty standard, but I'll briefly describe it for completeness:

Calculate $u^* = u^n + \Delta t (\dots)$, here the $\dots$ terms do not include the pressure component $\frac{1}{\rho} \triangledown p$
Determine the pressure $p$ so that when the pressure term is included, the fluid is incompressible, i.e. $\triangledown \cdot (u^* + \frac{\Delta t}{\rho} \triangledown p) = 0$
Calculate $u^* = u^n + \Delta t (\dots)$, this time including the pressure term.

Step 2 is a poisson equation: $ \triangledown \cdot \triangledown p = \frac{\rho}{\Delta t}  \triangledown \cdot u^* $
Normally, I'd solve a poisson equation using central differences to approximate the second derivative like this:
$\frac{\partial^2 p }{\partial^2 x} \approx \frac{p_{i-1} -2 p_i + p_{i+1}}{\Delta x^2} $
However, when I evaluate the pressure term in step 3, I am using a central difference to approximate the gradient:
$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} \approx \frac{p_{i+1} - p_{i-1}}{2\Delta x}$
Taking the divergence of that approximated gradient leads to:
$\frac{\partial^2 p }{\partial^2 x} \approx \frac{p_{i-2} -2 p_i + p_{i+2}}{4\Delta x^2} $
If I calculate the pressure using the first expression for the second derivative and apply it to the velocity, I notice that it's divergence is not zero. If I calculate the pressure using the second expression for the second derivative, the divergence is zero.
So now for my question: Is this a common solution? The literature I'm using does not mention it. And if not, how is this usually solved in practice? Or perhaps this is not mentioned because this is not actually a problem and my original code just had a bug. That is always a possibility.


have found that if I truly want zero divergence, I need to solve the Poisson equation using that second approximation for the second derivative.

How did you reach this conclusion?

I reached that conclusion, because I tried both versions, and only the second gave me good results.

The things that come to mind are:

The second finite difference is of higher order. Try a more refined mesh with the first  expression. You can try this high order classic one too:

[
f''(x) \approx \frac{-f(x+2h) + 16f(x+h) - 30f(x) + 16f(x-h) - f(x-2h)}{12h^2}
]

Sometimes you might get lucky and erros will cancel out. If your code allows it try a non-uniform grid.


The first approximation is obtained by taking the discrete gradient then the discrete divergence, but on a staggered grid with a step size of $\Delta x / 2$. Since you do it twice, it ends up only needing information from existing grid points. In your second approximation, you took the discrete gradient and divergence with spacing $\Delta x$. I am assuming the divergence you are using in the momentum equation is also using this spacing, so the two discrete operators are consistent and you get exact discrete incompressibility.
As for whether this is common, I don’t know enough about finite differences in CFD to say. They are commonly used for DNS, so I assume there is some way to make them accurate and consistent. It is for this reason that finite volume methods and various finite element methods are popular choices for CFD, as you can control the divergence-free condition as a modeling decision when choosing the function spaces and corresponding bases for the discretization.

I see some sources using staggered grids, this might be part of the reason why. This cleared up a lot.
